# magento and sugar CRM integration issue

Tags: magento, integration, sugarcrm

I am new in magento .Actually I want to integrate magento with sugar crm
I fallow this guide http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/magento-sugarcrm_integration_guide

but I am unable to get the customer first name, last name and email through this code.

When a customer create a account in magento a leads create in CRM but with empty field.
How can I get the customer first name last name and email .

Thanks allot in advance
this is my code but still unable to get customer info.
  public function createPostAction()
    {

```
    $session = $this->_getSession();




    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session->setEscapeMessages(true); // prevent XSS injection in user input
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $errors = array();

        if (!$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setId(null);
        }

        /* @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
      $customerForm= Mage::getModel('customer/form');
       $customerForm->setFormCode('customer_account_create')
            ->setEntity($customer);

       $customerData= $customerForm->extractData($this->getRequest());

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
            $customer->setIsSubscribed(1);
        }


        /**
         * Initialize customer group id
         */
        $customer->getGroupId();

        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('create_address')) {
            /* @var $address Mage_Customer_Model_Address */
            $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
            /* @var $addressForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
            $addressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
            $addressForm->setFormCode('customer_register_address')
                ->setEntity($address);

            $addressData    = $addressForm->extractData($this->getRequest(), 'address', false);
            $addressErrors  = $addressForm->validateData($addressData);
            if ($addressErrors === true) {
                $address->setId(null)
                    ->setIsDefaultBilling($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing', false))
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping', false));
                $addressForm->compactData($addressData);
                $customer->addAddress($address);

                $addressErrors = $address->validate();
                if (is_array($addressErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($errors, $addressErrors);
                }
            } else {
                $errors = array_merge($errors, $addressErrors);
            }




        }
        foreach (Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset('customer_account') as $code=>$node) {
                if ($node->is('create') && isset($data[$code])) {
                    switch($code) {
                        case 'email':
                            $data[$code] = trim($data[$code]);
                            echo $email = $data[$code];
                        break;
                        case 'firstname':
                           echo $firstname = $data[$code];
                        break;
                        case 'lastname':
                           echo $lastname = $data[$code];
                        break;
                    }               
                }
            }
        $options= array( "location"=>'http://addres.com/soap.php',"uri"=>'http://addres.com/',"trace"=>1 );
        $user_auth=array ("user_name"=>'name',
        "password"=>md5('password'),
        "version"=>'6.2.4'
        );


        $client=new SoapClient(Null,$options);
        $response=$client->login($user_auth,'name');
        $session_id=$response->id;

        $response=$client->set_entry($session_id,'Leads',array(
        array("name"=>'first_name',"value"=>$firstname),
        array("name"=>'last_name',"value"=>$lastname),
        array("name"=>'email',"value"=>$email)));            


        try {
            $customerErrors = $customerForm->validateData($customerData);
            if ($customerErrors !== true) {
                $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
            } else {
                $customerForm->compactData($customerData);
                $customer->setPassword($this->getRequest()->getPost('password'));
                $customer->setConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation'));
                $customerErrors = $customer->validate();
                if (is_array($customerErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
                }
            }

            $validationResult = count($errors) == 0;

            if (true === $validationResult) {
                $customer->save();



                Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
                    array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
                );

                if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
                    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
                        'confirmation',
                        $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),
                        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
                    );
                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));
                    $this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true)));
                    return;
                } else {
                    $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);
                    $this->_redirectSuccess($url);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                if (is_array($errors)) {
                    foreach ($errors as $errorMessage) {
                        $session->addError($errorMessage);
                    }
                } else {
                    $session->addError($this->__('Invalid customer data'));
                }
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
                $session->setEscapeMessages(false);
            } else {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $session->addError($message);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
        }
    } 


    $this->_redirectError(Mage::getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true)));



}
```

Comment: Please mark as correct answer or add your own answer and mark it correct..

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Mage_Customer_AccountController` and change `createPostAction` in which you can get customer fields using below code :

```
    foreach (Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset('customer_account') as $code=>$node) {
        if ($node->is('create') && isset($data[$code])) {
            switch($code) {
                case 'email':
                    $data[$code] = trim($data[$code]);
                    $email = $data[$code];
                break;
                case 'firstname':
                    $firstname = $data[$code];
                break;
                case 'lastname':
                    $lastname = $data[$code];
                break;
            }               
        }
    }
```

You can pass derived variables into your methods to process further.

Comment: thanks for your response this is my function. add your code into the function but still unable to get and pass the customer info

Comment: Have you checked $email,$firstname and $lastname contains required value or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting all the post data using

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

I know that for magento's contact form it produces an array which looks like this - probably very similar for creating an account.

```
(
    [name] => test
    [email] => test@test.com
    [telephone] => 
    [comment] => test
    [captcha] => Array
        (
            [contact_form] => tttt
        )

    [hideit] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
// Pass customer information from Magento to SugarCRM
$customer_info = array(array('name' => 'first_name', 'value' => $this->getRequest()->getPost('firstname')),
                   array('name' => 'last_name', 'value' => $this->getRequest()->getPost('lastname')),
                   array('name' => 'email2', 'value' => $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')));

$response = $client->set_entry($session_id, 'Leads', $customer_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overidding a controller file you can also use magento events handling.

customer_save_after is the event which gets called after a new customer registration.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events

```
<events>
    <customer_save_after>
        <observers>
            <yournamespace_yourmodule_order_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Yournamespace_Yourmodule_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>sendemail</method>
            </yournamespace_yourmodule_order_observer>
        </observers>
    </customer_save_after>
</events>
```

Here is the sample code to be included in your module config file to files

Now create a file with name Observer.php in your Model folder and put following code:

```
<?php
class Yournamespace_Yourmodule_Model_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //Just constrcutor for fun :-)
    }

    public function sendemail($observer)
    {
        //$observer contains the object returns in the event.
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        mage::log($order->getId());
        //Write code to send email
        return $this;
     }
```

}

Now whenever you will place order from anywhere in your magento store your function sendemail will be executed.